# Best way to go about making a roof for a complicated object

Tags: modeling, mesh

Wondering what would be the best method for creating a roof for this building. I don't what the roof to be anything other than a flat square that covers the top of the object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to 3D print it then:

1. Knife project the perimeter onto a plane
2. Remove unnecessary faces
3. Lower the roof to .001 above the model
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  to combine.

Comment: Can't really find any good knife project videos anywhere. When I attempt it either nothing happens or something very incorrect happens. Any chance you could be a bit more specific on how I should do this?

Comment: You must knife project in an **ortho** front/back, left/right or top/bottom view for the result to be correct.